# Storing a hotel menu in a database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

How to store a restaurants menu in a database. Say suppose I have a database called `hotel` with a table called `restaurant`. Here is the schema.

```
restaurant(Type, Name, Description, Pictures, Address, Menu)
```

Type, Name, Description, Address are strings, like `varchar.`
Pictures are blob type.

Now how do I store a Menu? Say that a restaurant has over a 100 items. It becomes meaningless to have a coloumn for each menu item. So how do I store it?

Can I use Json to overcome this? If so how?

Example of a menu:

```
Pasta: 5 euros
Pizza: 10 euros
.
.
.
similarly many items
```

And this is not a way I am looking for:

```
item(restrnt id, item, price)
```

The above will work well for a single restaurant with a large number of dishes.

Comment: Create a new table called 'menu', and include a foreign key back to 'restaurant'. No, don't store your menu as a JSON column - that will give you a lot of trouble in the long term.

Comment: how about a table of item:price: place

Comment: But including all the menu items in a table becomes a head ache right?

I can use a foreign key as halfer said, but storing all menu items in a row is really very big

Answer (score 1):

You have a table of menu items, and one column of that table will be a foreign key which will match the primary key in the `restaurant` table to associate the menu item with a particular restaurant.

If menu items can be shared between multiple restaurants, use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) instead (a third table with two columns - both foreign keys, one on the `restaurant` table and one on the `menu_items` table.

Comment: Yeah ok. But dont you think a table called menu(Restaurant id, Name, Price) may end up having too many rows?

Comment: No. Databases are very good at storing data. (And menus are tiny)

Comment: the table is relatively small (in width), and any database engine can handle millions of rows, especially if you take care in choosing the correct col data types and place correct indexes.

Comment: @Quentin Ohh Please stop the sarcasm. Ok if I do as per your solution then how do I overcome a problem like this:

Menu(Restrnt id, item, Price) This is for a single hotel menu, similarly if i want say 500 hotels menu, then?

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra — I haven't used any sarcasm on this page. How do you overcome a problem like what? You appear to have a solution there, not a problem.

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra I don't think anyone was beeing sarcastic, properly planning/normalizing/indexing your database is a big task on its own. I would suggest you read up on Database Normalization, it will definitly help you to get both faster and more structured databases :)

Comment: @Quentin: No, you are not getting what I am trying to say. If you are free can you please move this to chat, I want to clear some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table `items(id, name, description)`. This table will contain all the items you have in your restaurant. You can update it any time.

Make another table `item_prices(id, item_id,restaurant_id, price, update_date)`. Here `item_id` is the id of item you are referring from `items` table. On the long run, this schema would prove helpful, as its easy to maintain. You just need to update the `item_prices` table for any price change.

Similarly you make `restaurants(id, reatauran_name, ... )`

And better store images in filesystem rather as blob.

Comment: I dont want just 1 restaurant, I want a 100 restaurants with different menus for each restaurant.

Comment: so there is restaurant_id foreign key in item_prices table. 
when u fetch use `select items.name, items_prices.price from items, item_prices where items.id = item_prices.item_id and restaurant_id = 2 `

Answer (score 0):

I would start off with something like this, ofcourse it has to be edited to suit your needs.

```
item (id, title, description)

menu (id, restaurant_id, title, description, active_from, active_to)

menu_item (id, menu_id, restaurant_id, price)

picture (id, title, description, filename, active)

restaurant (id, type, name, description, address)

restaurant_picture (id, restaurant_id, picture_id)
```

Using a proper normalized model then one restaurant can have several menus, which can have several items.

I suggest you read up on database normalization.